# How do I expose extra ports on my Google Compute Instance using Terraform?

Tags: google-compute-engine, terraform

I have a Google Compute Instance defined by some Terraform code.

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = "${file("auth.json")}"
  project     = "aqueous-depth-189023"
  region      = "europe-west2"
}

resource "google_project" "website" {
  name = "Website"
  project_id = "aqueous-depth-189023"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = "website"
  machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
  zone         = "europe-west1-b"

  network_interface {
    network = "default"

    access_config {
      // Ephemeral IP
    }
  }

  metadata {
    sshKeys = "james:${file("website.pem.pub")}"
  }

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-8"
    }
  }
}
```

By default, Google only exposes port 22 and a few others for Google Compute Instances. Can I update my Terraform code so as to achieve exposing port 80 and some other ports, without having to resort to using the web console? What Terraform resource would I need to add or edit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`google_compute_firewall`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_firewall.html). You'll need to [`tag`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance.html#tags) your instance with the instance resource and set [`target_tags`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_firewall.html#target_tags) on the firewall resource. You can refer to how these tags work [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags).

### Example

#### Add a tag to the instance

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = "website"
  machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
  zone         = "europe-west1-b"

  tags = ["web"]

  network_interface {
    network = "default"

    access_config {
      // Ephemeral IP
    }
  }

  metadata {
    sshKeys = "james:${file("website.pem.pub")}"
  }

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-8"
    }
  }
}
```

#### Add a firewall resource

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "default" {
 name    = "web-firewall"
 network = "default"

 allow {
   protocol = "icmp"
 }

 allow {
   protocol = "tcp"
   ports    = ["80"]
 }

 source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
 target_tags = ["web"]
}
```

You'll also want to define [`source_tags`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_firewall.html#source_tags) or [`source_ranges`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_firewall.html#source_ranges), the example above uses a source range of `0.0.0.0/0` which is 'anything'. This may not be appropriate for all rules.

Comment: Rather than just linking to the docs this answer would be more useful if there was a summarised answer with a code example that was supplemented by linking to the docs for further information.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Updated with an example